# My CI job creates __pycache__ as root, can't clean the workspace on next run

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins

My Jenkins CI job check out a Python project from Git, build the application, run some tests, and then deploy the application to a server.

Usually, I set up my CI jobs to wipe the workspace between each run.

Somehow, the workspace now contains a __pycache__ folder owned by root. I don't know how root got set as a the owner (with 755 permissions), but in any case I no longer can wipe the workspace. I'm not sure how Jenkins and Python could make a file being owned by root in the first case, but haven't looked into this but guess it's a logical explanation for it.

How does other Python guys handle this? Is there a way to make this folder being owned by the user running Jenkins, so that Jenkins can wipe the workspace?

EDIT: I should mention that I run the Python application inside a Docker container.

Comment: Do you use Docker or any other similar environment in your Jenkins job? I've had the same problem caused by running the job in Docker container.

Comment: @RadimNovotny, yes I do. Found a solution/workaround though, by making sure the user inside the docker container has the same UID/GID as my host user, like this: https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15. By the way, I'll post this as my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution/workaround, by making sure the user inside the docker container has the same UID/GID as my host user, like this: https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15.